# How do I change a GameObject's rotation equal to my player camera's rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on a first person shooter. I have an aim function, which puts the pistol right in front of the camera, to make it look like your holding it in front of you. Im trying to make it so the pistol will also rotate with the camera on the Z axis, so that way the pistol wont stay still, because that looks odd and gets in the way. To do this, I tried this:
`GPR.gun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, plrCam.transform.rotation.z);`, however this ends up rotating the gun very slightly around the z axis, and mainly rotating it around the y axis whenever I move my camera. I am a beginner programmer in Unity so please try to make answers more digestible to beginners so I can understand it. Here is my full script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PistolFire : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Gun Properties

    public float range = 50f;
    public float damage = 10f;
    //Sensitivity decrease for looking down the sights
    public float downSights = 5f;

    //Other vars
    private playerGunControls playerGun;
    private GameObject plrCam;
    private Camera fpsCam;
    private ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
    private GameObject impactEffect;
    private bool aimed = false;
    private GameObject aimPos;
    private GunPickupRaycast GPR;
    private GameObject handPos;
    private GameObject Player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Getting objects because gun is instantiated, so this is necessary
        plrCam = GameObject.Find("Player Camera");
        playerGun = plrCam.GetComponent<playerGunControls>();
        fpsCam = plrCam.GetComponent<Camera>();
        muzzleFlash = GetComponentInChildren<ParticleSystem>();
        impactEffect = GameObject.Find("Impact Effect");
        aimPos = GameObject.Find("aimPos");
        GPR = plrCam.GetComponent<GunPickupRaycast>();
        handPos = GameObject.Find("Hand Pos");
        Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Check for shoot button down
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            if (playerGun.holding == "Pistol")
            {
                Shoot();
            }
        }
        //Check if aim button down
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire2"))
            {
            if (playerGun.holding == "Pistol")
            {
                Aim();
            }
        }
        //Check if no longer aiming to reset to normal
        if (aimed == true && !(Input.GetButton("Fire2")))
        {
            Unaim();
        }

    }
    void Shoot()
    {

        muzzleFlash.Play();

        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(plrCam.transform.position, plrCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            Health health = hit.transform.GetComponent<Health>();
            if (health != null)
            {
                health.TakeDamage(damage);
            }

            //Instantiate the Impact Effect
            GameObject IE = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(IE, 1.5f);

        }
    }
    void Aim()
    {
        aimed = true;
        Debug.Log("Aiming");
        GPR.gun.transform.position = aimPos.transform.position;
        GPR.gun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, plrCam.transform.rotation.z);
    }
    void Unaim()
    {
        GPR.gun.transform.position = handPos.transform.position;
        Debug.Log("No longer aiming");
        aimed = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by making the gun a child of my camera instead of a child of my player.

Comment: Jeremys556: Thank you for self-answering your question, which really benefits everyone. But it would be a much better answer if you offered some code, that explains what you did, instead of simply describing it in words. You can improve your answer alot by reading this resource: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer